# compare row values in % to measure growth

Tags: mysql, sql

i am storing weekly values of a type in my database, let's orders per user.

So i have

```
1. Tim | 10 | 1 
2. Tim | 20 | 2
2. Bob | 10 | 1
2. Bob | 25 | 2
```

Tim has sold 10 items in week 1 and 20 in week 2
Bob has sols 10 items in week 1 and 25 in week 2

Now i am trying to create a mysql query which i can use in my php to create a table which results in:

```
Tim: 10 > 20 (100%)
Bob: 10 > 25 (150%)
```

Preferably i only use 1 query to save my database instead of a loop with several queries per user.

**Edit:**
I do not have the exact weeknumber, I just have timestamps, and I want to compare the 2 latest. This is what I have now, but gives an error:

```
SELECT   userid, 
         (select sold order by sold limit 0,1) as last, 
         (select sold order by sold limit 1,1) as semilast 
FROM     sales 
GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: Do you need these results only for weeks 1 and 2?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, when you create a question, make a question... It seems that you are requesting a solution. Keep in mind that SO is not a free coding service. Always try to give one sample input (ok), you expected output (ok), what did you try and what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
SELECT 
  t2.name, 
  t2.week AS from_week, t1.week AS to_week, 
  t2.sold_items AS from_sold, t1.sold_items AS to_sold, 
  ((t1.sold_items - t2.sold_items) / t2.sold_items) * 100 AS growth 
FROM table_name t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, sold_items, week FROM table_name
) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.week = t2.week + 1
HAVING growth IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name, t1.week
```

Since MySQL 8.0 you can also use [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag):

```
SELECT t.*,
  ((to_sold - from_sold) / from_sold) * 100 AS growth
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    LAG(week) OVER wCompare AS from_week,
    week AS to_week,
    LAG(sold_items) OVER wCompare AS from_sold,
    sold_items AS to_sold
  FROM table_name
  WINDOW wCompare AS (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY week)
) t HAVING growth IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name, from_week
```

**Note:** You can remove the `HAVING` to see all records (the records without change too).

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aaab2c606f41e6750347000afd43bb9d)

Answer (score 0):

To get your expected results you need to `group by name` and concatenate the columns like this:

```
select 
  concat(
    name, ': ', 
    group_concat(sold_items order by week separator ' > '), 
    ' (', 
    round(100 * (max(case when week = 2 then sold_items end) / max(case when week = 1 then sold_items end) - 1), 0), 
    '%)'
  ) result
from tablename
where week in (1, 2)
group by name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5CKDe4dQXxf3ddkueLhPz7/0).
Results:

```
| result              |
| ------------------- |
| Bob: 10 > 25 (150%) |
| Tim: 10 > 20 (100%) |
```

Comment: thanks, just like that, only in my case i do not have the exact weeknumber, i just have timestamps, and i want to compare the 2 latest.

This is what i have now, but gives an error


`SELECT userid,
(select sold order by sold limit 0,1) as last,
(select sold order by sold limit 1,1) as semilast
FROM sales
group by userid`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your real table look like this:

```
+--------+------+---------------------+
| userid | sold |      datesold       |
+--------+------+---------------------+
| Tim    |  10  | 2019-10-03 11:16:10 |
| Tim    |  20  | 2019-10-10 11:16:10 |
| Bob    |   5  | 2019-10-03 11:16:10 |
| Bob    |   5  | 2019-10-04 11:16:10 |
| Bob    |  25  | 2019-10-10 11:16:10 |
+--------+- ----+---------------------+
```

*Note that I purposely separate Bob's quantity into two consecutive dates from the same week for this example.

You can obtain the week by using [WEEK()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_week.asp). So, with a query like below:

```
SELECT userid,sold,datesold,WEEK(datesold) as wk FROM sales;
```

you will get a result like following:

```
+---------+------+---------------------+----+
| userid | sold |      datesold       | wk |
+---------+------+---------------------+----+
| Tim     |  10  | 2019-10-03 11:16:10 | 39 |
| Tim     |  20  | 2019-10-10 11:16:10 | 40 |
| Bob     |   5  | 2019-10-03 11:16:10 | 39 |
| Bob     |   5  | 2019-10-04 11:16:10 | 39 |
| Bob     |  25  | 2019-10-10 11:16:10 | 40 |
+---------+------+---------------------+----+
```

We add `SUM(sold)` and `GROUP BY userid,wk` to the query above:

```
SELECT   userid,SUM(sold) AS tqty,datesold,WEEK(datesold) AS wk 
FROM     sales
GROUP BY userid,wk;
```

Then combining this with the query provided by Sebastian:

```
SELECT    t2.userid, 
          t2.wk AS from_week, 
          WEEK(t1.datesold) AS to_week, 
          t2.tqty AS from_sold, 
          t1.sold AS to_sold, 
          ((t1.sold - t2.tqty) / t2.tqty) * 100 AS growth 
FROM       sales t1 
LEFT JOIN (

  SELECT   userid, SUM(sold) AS tqty, WEEK(datesold) AS wk 
  FROM     sales 
  GROUP BY userid, wk

) t2 
ON        t1.userid = t2.userid 
AND       WEEK(t1.datesold) = t2.wk + 1
HAVING    growth IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  userid, WEEK(t1.datesold);
```

With the following result:

```
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
| userid | from_week | to_week | from_sold | to_sold |  growth  |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
| Bob    |        39 |      40 |        10 |      25 | 150.0000 |
| Tim    |        39 |      40 |        10 |      20 | 100.0000 |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
```